# Each row iterate through n columns

Tags: c#, .net

I have the code below. To explain there will always be values for the 'tl' variable.
At the moment its hard coded to always assume 4 columns in the row, but I want to make it work based on the count of the columns and make it build the levels based on how many columns there are, but there also needs to be a value in the column.

So at the moment if there is a value in column 2, it will build the 'ltwo' variable, and then if there is a value in column 3 it does the 'lthree'.
I want to make it build as many levels as it needs to so im not repeating code and having the same code over and over.

```
public static List<AdditionalPropertyType> SQLAddPropsStructured(DataTable dataTable, List<AdditionalPropertyType> currentadditionalproperties)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        var tl = new AdditionalPropertyType
        {
            Name = row[0].ToString(),
            Value = row[1].ToString()
        };

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row[2].ToString()))
        {
            var ltwo = new AdditionalPropertyType
            {
                Name = row[2].ToString()
            };
            var ltwolist = new List<AdditionalPropertyType>();
            ltwolist.Add(tl);
            ltwo.AdditionalProperties = ltwolist;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row[3].ToString()))
            {
                var lthree = new AdditionalPropertyType
                {
                    Name = row[3].ToString()
                };
                var lthreelist = new List<AdditionalPropertyType>();
                lthreelist.Add(ltwo);
                lthree.AdditionalProperties = lthreelist;

                currentadditionalproperties.Insert(0, lthree);
            }
            else
                currentadditionalproperties.Insert(0, ltwo);
        }
        else
            currentadditionalproperties.Insert(0, tl);
    }
    return currentadditionalproperties;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to **reverse** your condition and make use of the keyword **continue**

```
public static List<AdditionalPropertyType> SQLAddPropsStructured(DataTable dataTable, List<AdditionalPropertyType> currentadditionalproperties)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        var tl = new AdditionalPropertyType
        {
            Name = row[0].ToString(),
            Value = row[1].ToString()
        };

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row[2].ToString())){
             currentadditionalproperties.Insert(0, tl);
             continue;
        }

        var ltwo = new AdditionalPropertyType
        {
            Name = row[2].ToString()
        };
        var ltwolist = new List<AdditionalPropertyType>();
        ltwolist.Add(tl);
        ltwo.AdditionalProperties = ltwolist;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row[3].ToString())) {
            currentadditionalproperties.Insert(0, ltwo);
            continue;
        }

        var lthree = new AdditionalPropertyType
        {
            Name = row[3].ToString()
        };
        var lthreelist = new List<AdditionalPropertyType>();
        lthreelist.Add(ltwo);
        lthree.AdditionalProperties = lthreelist;

        currentadditionalproperties.Insert(0, lthree);                                            
    }
    return currentadditionalproperties;
}
```

Now, the code is clearer. The next step is to collect the **repeating** cases. Note the second case onward is **repeating**. Thus, do further simplification:

```
public static List<AdditionalPropertyType> SQLAddPropsStructured(DataTable dataTable, List<AdditionalPropertyType> currentadditionalproperties)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        var tlprev = new AdditionalPropertyType
        {
            Name = row[0].ToString(),
            Value = row[1].ToString()
        };

        bool isTlUpdated = true;
        for (int i = 2; i <= 3; ++i) { //change this according to your need
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row[i].ToString()) && isTlUpdated){
                currentadditionalproperties.Insert(0, tlprev);
                isTlUpdated = false;
                break; //note that this will now change to break to break from the current for-loop
            }

            var lnext = new AdditionalPropertyType
            {
                Name = row[i].ToString()
            };
            var lnextlist = new List<AdditionalPropertyType>();
            lnextlist.Add(tlprev);
            lnext.AdditionalProperties = lnextlist;
            tlprev = lnext; //need to record this for the next loop or end of the case
            isTlUpdated = true;
        }

        if (isTlUpdated) //correction by Jeroen
            currentadditionalproperties.Insert(0, tlprev);                                            
    }
    return currentadditionalproperties;
}
```

The key is to simplify the code step-by-step

Comment: hi, yes this is what i was looking for, just changed the 3 in the for loop to the count of the columns, thanks

Comment: you are welcome. ;) the key is to edit little by little till we see the repeating pattern. In your case, it can be done by **reversing the condition**.

Comment: There is a bug, when all columns are not null or empty, nothing will be added.  and if some are empty, it will be added twice...

Comment: @paulmezza Note that I put the flag there to prevent the unupdated `tlprev` getting inserted twice. I also put the flag at the last.

Comment: the flag is only preventing for insertion for the thrid time.. notice the `currentadditionalproperties.Insert(0, tlprev);` below the interation. I recomment using break instead of continue with a flag.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen the flag is also updated back to true if the update occurs. Ok, I noted it. I added the condition before the last statement.

Comment: @paulmezza note that, since there is additional for-loop nest, the `continue` keyword is changed to `break` to keep the case equivalent. Otherwise, it won't be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the columns using the Columns property of the DataTable:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(column.ColumnName + " = " + row[column]);
    }
}
```

---

You probably want to do something like this:  *(written on the websites, some minor typos can be present)*

You need to iterate the additional columns and check if there is a value present. When there is a value, create a backup reference and renew your property.

```
public static List<AdditionalPropertyType> SQLAddPropsStructured(DataTable dataTable, List<AdditionalPropertyType> currentadditionalproperties)
{
    // check if there are atleast 2 columns defined
    if(dataTable.Columns.Count < 2)
        throw new Exception("At least two columns are required");

    // The result
    var currentadditionalproperties = new List<AdditionalPropertyType>();

    // iterate the rows
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        // create the base property
        var tl = new AdditionalPropertyType
        {
            Name = row[0].ToString(),
            Value = row[1].ToString()
        };

        // check the rest of the columns for additional names
        foreach(int index=2;index<dataTable.Columns.Count;index++)
        {
            var columnValue = row[index].ToString();

            // if the column is empty, discontinue the iteration
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(columnValue))
                break;

            // create a backup reference.
            var previous = tl;

            // create a new AdditionalPropertyType
            var tl = new AdditionalPropertyType { Name = columnValue };
            // Create the list
            tl.AdditionalProperties = new List<AdditionalPropertyType>();
            // add the previous (backup reference)
            tl.AdditionalProperties.Add(previous);
        }
        // insert the 'chain' of additional properties on the list at possition 0
        currentadditionalproperties.Insert(0, tl);
    }
    // return the list
    return currentadditionalproperties;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted all your code, so I had to guess in a couple of places (such as what the "currentAdditionalProperties" does).

I think that the below code illustrates what you want to do by making the logic extendable depending on how many columns the data table has.

The trick is to just store the "last thing" in a variable, so it can be used for the "current thing". At the end, whatever was the "last thing" is what you want to store in your "currentAdditionalProperties" object. I have commented so you can see the logic.

```
    private List<AdditionalPropertyType> SQLAddPropsStructured(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        AdditionalPropertyType lastNewType;             // to remember the previous new instance

        // for all rows...
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            // the first type takes name and value from the first two fields
            AdditionalPropertyType newType = new AdditionalPropertyType();
            newType.Name = row[0].ToString();
            newType.Value = row[1].ToString();

            // remember this type: it is used as the AdditionalProperties for the NEXT type
            lastNewType = newType;

            // additional types start from field 2
            int field = 2;

            // iterate until we find a NULL  field.
            // If you want to check for the end of the fields rather than a NULL value, then instead use:
            //      while(field < dataTable.Columns.Count)
            while(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row[field].ToString()))
            {
                // create new type
                var newSubType = new AdditionalPropertyType();

                // get name
                Name = row[field].ToString();

                // new type takes the PREVIOUS type as its additional parameters
                List<AdditionalPropertyType> propertyData = new List<AdditionalPropertyType>();
                propertyData.Add(lastNewType);
                newSubType.AdditionalProperties = propertyData;

                // remember THIS type for the NEXT type
                lastNewType = newSubType;

                // process next field (if valid)
                field++;
            }


            // put the last set of properties found into the current properties
            currentAdditionalProperties.Insert(0, lastNewType);
            return currentAdditionalProperties;
        }
    }
```